# Unknown occourance of specific phrase in Wordpress theme PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, gettext

I have a Wordpress theme, and when I go through the theme, I notice this line `hdb-theme`. I'm personally confused on what's the importance of this, what does it do, and if it has any effect if I remove it.

Here are some examples of where this pops up in my theme's PHP files:

`<?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'hbd-theme' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>`

`<?php comment_form_title( __('Post a Comment', 'hbd-theme'), __('Post a Reply to %s', 'hbd-theme') ); ?>`

So can anybody explain to me what the importance of '**hdb-theme**' is?

**EDIT:**

I have found this article on StackOverFlow explaining it: [Wordpress theme name inside theme php files, what is the purpose of this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388764/wordpress-theme-name-inside-theme-php-files-what-is-the-purpose-of-this)

Although can somebody explain it a little bit better to me? I'm just a beginner Wordpress theme developer. Also, is it okay if I remove it from my theme? Will it have a big effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with localization - i.e. translations to different languages. It's a convention that WordPress uses in case you want to develop a product that can be used in multiple languages around the world - i.e. Spanish, Russian, German, etc.

So to answer you question, if you remove the `hdb-theme`, then potential future contributors that want to translate your theme to different languages will have a harder time :)

Here is more information about the technology straight from the WordPress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Localization_Technology.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! I now understand it better! Although, my site is totally English and currently for English viewers only. So if I remove it, it be okay, right?

Comment: I suppose so, but keeping it there won't hurt either. Ultimately it is your call.